# grab multiple lines after a matching target line

Tags: scripting, perl

This question is similar to [How to show lines after each grep match until other specific match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21076/how-to-show-lines-after-each-grep-match-until-other-specific-match) thus answers may be similar to those there.

I am trying to grab and extract from a file the lines that are after the lines that are matching a TARGET value ("forms=2", in my case) and the next empty line.
The segment of my file is like below:

```
forms=1
Code=00416T0
Code=00416T0

forms=2       #Target**
Code=06538T0  #grab this line
Code=06538T0  #grab this line
Code=11288T0  #grab this line
Code=11288T0  #grab this line

forms=1
Code=00549T0
Code=00549T0
Code=00549T0

forms=2      #Target**
Code=00553T0 #grab this line
Code=02576T0 #grab this line
Code=02576T0 #grab this line

forms=1
Code=11099T0
```

So I would like to find a way according to Target "forms=2" to have the following lines even if same of those grabbing lines are identical

```
Code=06538T0 #grab this line
Code=06538T0 #grab this line
Code=11288T0 #grab this line
Code=11288T0 #grab this line
Code=00553T0 #grab this line
Code=02576T0 #grab this line
Code=02576T0 #grab this line
```

Any help please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show lines after each grep match until other specific match?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21076/how-to-show-lines-after-each-grep-match-until-other-specific-match)

Comment: @Mat I guess that you need a better duplicate; the referenced one includes the lines matching the pattern whereas in this case you need to exclude those.

Answer (score 2):

The following might work for you:

```
sed -n '/forms=2/,/^[^C]/{/^[^C]/b;p}' filename
```

or, as suggested by [Graeme](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/48083/graeme):

```
sed -n '/^forms=2/,/^[^C]/ {/^Code=/p}' filename
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
Code=06538T0  #grab this line
Code=06538T0  #grab this line
Code=11288T0  #grab this line
Code=11288T0  #grab this line
Code=00553T0 #grab this line
Code=02576T0 #grab this line
Code=02576T0 #grab this line
```

---

For handling cases where you might lines like `form=20`, you could say:

```
sed -n '/^forms=2\b/,/^[^C]/ {/^Code=/p}' filename
```

Comment: This is good, I would do it like this though `sed -n '/^forms=2/,/^[^C]/ {/^Code=/p}'`. Only thing I can't figure out though is how to exclude sections with `forms=20` without using extended regex.

Comment: @Graeme Yes, your suggestion makes sense.  See the edit above for handling `forms=20` case.

Comment: That works, I have no idea why though. `\b` is backspace, right?

Comment: @Graeme Word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`:

```
%perl -lne 'if(/forms=2/.../^$/ and $_!~/forms=2|^$/){print}' file
Code=06538T0  #grab this line
Code=06538T0  #grab this line
Code=11288T0  #grab this line
Code=11288T0  #grab this line
Code=00553T0 #grab this line
Code=02576T0 #grab this line
Code=02576T0 #grab this line
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/forms=2/,/^$/{if(!/forms=2/&&!/^$/)print}' file
```

or:

```
awk '/^$/{flag=0};flag;/forms=2/{flag=1}' file
```

Using `sed` (GNU sed):

```
sed '/forms=2/,/^$/{//!b};d'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another sed:

```
sed -n '/forms=2 /,/^$/ {/^.*forms.*$/d; /^$/d; s/  *#grab/ #grab/}' input
```

.

```
Code=06538T0 #grab this line
Code=06538T0 #grab this line
Code=11288T0 #grab this line
Code=11288T0 #grab this line
Code=00553T0 #grab this line
Code=02576T0 #grab this line
Code=02576T0 #grab this line
```

Comment: What if there was a line like this `forms=20`?

Comment: Also, I think this can be condensed to `sed -n '/forms=2/,/^$/ {s/[ ][ ]*#grab/ #grab/p}'`. You don't need to `d` if you already have `-n`, just add the `p` to the end of the substitution.

Comment: Thats is also what i was looking!!