# Pass shell variable as a /pattern/ to awk

Tags: shell, awk, quoting, variable

Having the following in one of my shell functions:

```
function _process () {
  awk -v l="$line" '
  BEGIN {p=0}
  /'"$1"'/ {p=1}
  END{ if(p) print l >> "outfile.txt" }
  '
}
```

, so when called as `_process $arg`, `$arg` gets passed as `$1`, and used as a search pattern. It works this way, because shell expands `$1` in place of awk pattern! Also `l` can be used inside awk program, being declared with `-v l="$line"`. All fine.

Is it possible in same manner give pattern to search as a variable?

Following will not work,

```
awk -v l="$line" -v search="$pattern" '
  BEGIN {p=0}
  /search/ {p=1}
  END{ if(p) print l >> "outfile.txt" }
  '
```

,as awk will not interpret `/search/` as a variable, but instead literally.

Comment: What you're searching for is not text that matches a "pattern", it's text that matches either a string or a regular expression. See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for why that matters and why you shouldn't use the word "pattern" in this context.

Comment: See also [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for a comprehensive answer to the question of how to pass the value of shell variables or other values to an awk script.

Comment: I've been reading a lot of info about awk and passing variables, etc. topics so apologies if I am a bit confused, but, although above answers are very good, IMO, fail to address one of OPs questions, whether it is possible or not to use "/search/" as variable. To me it sounds it is not possible, but I fail to see why or where is this stated

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use awk's `~` operator, and you don't need to provide a literal regex on the right-hand side:

```
function _process () {
    awk -v l="$line" -v pattern="$1" '
        $0 ~ pattern {p=1; exit} 
        END {if(p) print l >> "outfile.txt"}
    '  
}
```

Here calling `exit` upon the first match as we don't need to read the rest. You don't even need `awk`, `grep` would be enough and likely more efficient and avoid the problem of `awk`'s `-v var='value'` doing backslash processing:

```
function _process () {
    grep -qe "$1" && printf '%s\n' "$line"
}
```

Depending on the pattern, you may want `grep -Eqe "$1"`

Comment: This is exactly what solves this in a way I wanted (1st example), because it keeps the semantics, which was my goal. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't note the removal of the BEGIN block: an unassigned variable is treated as 0 in a numeric context or the empty string otherwise. So, an unassigned variable will be false in `if (p) ...`

Comment: yes I noticed, it needs to be set on BEGIN block to zero each time, as it serves as a switch. But interestingly I tried now script using `$0 ~ pattern`, and it does not work, however with `/'"$1"'/` it does work!? :O

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the way `$line` is retrieved, pattern search is done on the output of `whois $line`, `$line` coming from file in a WHILE DO block.

Comment: Please show the contents of `$line` -- do it in your question for proper formatting.

Comment: Don't write `/$0 ~ search/` -- leave out the slashes: `$0 ~ search`

Comment: It seems that this: `awk '$0 ~ /foo/ { print $0 }'` is actually equivalent to this: `awk -v pattern=foo '$0 ~ pattern { print $0 }`. In other words, the `//` brackets are not needed anymore at all, because `pattern` becomes a [dynamic regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html#Computed-Regexps). Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 22):

```bash
awk  -v pattern="$1" '$0 ~ pattern'
```

Has an issue in that `awk` expands the ANSI C escape sequences (like `\n` for newline, `\f` for form feed, `\\` for backslash and so on) in `$1`. So it becomes an issue if `$1` contains backslash characters which is common in regular expressions (with GNU `awk` 4.2 or above, [values that start with `@/` and end in `/`, are also a problem](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants)). Another approach that doesn't suffer from that issue is to write it:

```bash
PATTERN=$1 awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["PATTERN"]'
```

How bad it's going to be will depend on the `awk` implementation.

```
$ nawk -v 'a=\.' 'BEGIN {print a}'
.
$ mawk -v 'a=\.' 'BEGIN {print a}'
\.
$ busybox awk -v 'a=\.' 'BEGIN {print a}'
.
$ gawk -v 'a=\.' 'BEGIN {print a}'
gawk: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
.
$ gawk5.0.1 -v 'a=@/foo/' BEGIN {print a}'
foo
```

All `awk`s work the same for valid escape sequences though:

```
$ a='\\-\b' awk 'BEGIN {print ENVIRON["a"]}' | od -vtx1 -tc
0000000  5c  5c  2d  5c  62  0a
          \   \   -   \   b  \n
0000006
```

(content of `$a` passed as-is)

```
$ awk -v a='\\-\b' 'BEGIN {print a}' | od -vtx1 -tc
0000000  5c  2d  08  0a
          \   -  \b  \n
0000004
```

(`\\` changed to `\` and `\b` changed to a backspace character).

Comment: So you are saying that if pattern was for example `\d{3}` to find three digits, that wouldn't work as expected, if I understood you well?

Comment: for `\d` which is not a valid C escape sequence, that depends on your `awk` implementation (run `awk -v 'a=\d{3}' 'BEGIN{print a}'` to check). But for `\\` or `\b`, yes definitely. (BTW, I don't know of any awk implementations that understands `\d` as meaning a digit).

Comment: it says: awk warning - escape sequence `\d' treated as plain `d' d{3}, so I guess I would have a problem in this case?

Comment: so to resume, I am safe with ENVIRON["pattern"] approach?

Comment: Yes. see [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A22565+awk+ENVIRON) for more reading.

Comment: Ok, again not working.. when I replace `$0 ~ pattern` for `$0 ~ ENVIRON["pattern"]`, I get matches everywhere, so all my lines from `infile` get copied over to `outfile`. First one was working ok (one with `$0 ~ pattern`)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I had a typo in my answer. The name of then environment variable has to match `ENVIRON["PATTERN"]` for the `PATTERN` environment variable. If you want to use a shell variable, you need to export it first (`export variable`) or use the `ENV=VALUE awk '...ENVIRON["ENV"]'` env-var passing syntax as in my answer.

Comment: it works if PATTERN set each time while looping in front of awk, if I put PATTERN="$1" before the loop it does not work.. why?

Comment: Because you need to export a shell variable for it to be passed in the environment to a command.

Comment: Even in same shell script, didn't know that, it works now, just changed `PATTERN="$1"` to `export PATTERN="$1"`. Maybe because awk was sent input through the pipe.. Anyway learned a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Try something like:

```
awk -v l="$line" -v search="$pattern" 'BEGIN {p=0}; { if ( match( $0, search )) {p=1}}; END{ if(p) print l >> "outfile.txt" }'
```

Comment: If this behaves same as `/regex/` in terms of finding pattern, this could be a nice solution. I will try.

Comment: The quick tests I ran seemed to work the same, but I won't even begin to guarantee it... :)

Comment: But what if `$pattern` (and therefore `search`) contains something that can be treated as a part of regex, like `[`? And I want to search for a literal match?

Answer (score -1):

No, but you can simply interpolate the pattern into the double-quoted string you pass to awk:

```
awk -v l="$line" "BEGIN {p=0}; /$pattern/ {p=1}; END{ if(p) print l >> \"outfile.txt\" }"
```

Note that you now have to escape the double-quoted awk literal, but it is still the simplest way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Is this way safe if `$pattern` contains spaces, my example from above will work as $1 is protected with "$1" double quotes, however not shure what happens in your case.

Comment: Your original example ends the single-quoted string at the second `'`, then protects the `$1` via double quotes and then tacks another single-quoted string for the second half of the awk program. If I understand correctly, this should have exactly the same effect as protecting the `$1` via the outer single quotes - awk never sees the double quotes that you put around it.

Comment: But if `$pattern` contains `^/ {system("rm -rf /")};`, then you're in big trouble.

Comment: is that downside of this approach only, having all wrapped in "" ?

Answer (score -3):

You could use the eval function which resolves in this example the nets variable before the awk is run.

```
nets="searchtext"
eval "awk '/"${nets}"/'" file.txt
```