# use awk with input from a variable

Tags: awk

i need to fetch n+9th line from the occurance of a specific word which is store in  variable i from a file LIST.txt

Below is the command

```
Used_pages=`awk '/${i}/{nr[NR+9]}; NR in nr'  LIST.txt`
```

it works when i do a test run on the file by replacing the variable $i with one of the values like

```
 awk '/APPLE/{nr[NR+9]}; NR in nr'  LIST.txt
```

Please help me figgure out how to use the same command with the variable.

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? [Pass shell variable as pattern to awk](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` has the `-v` parameter for setting variables.  To set the variable `$i` in `awk`, you would say `awk -v i=$i` and then within the `awk` statement, simply reference the variable as `i` rather than `$i`.

I haven't tested the following, but try this:

```
used_pages="$(awk -v i=$i '/i/{nr[NR+9]}; NR in nr' LIST.txt)"
```