# Using bash variable with escape character in awk to extract lines from file

Tags: bash, awk

I am writing a bash script (just learning bash) to extract some lines from a file based on two patterns. The first pattern is just a sentence ending in a colon. The second pattern is a `*` repeated N (in this case 58) times.

An example file:

```
lines I don not want
lines I don not want
lines I don not want

A sentence here:
********************************************************
lines I want
lines I want
lines I want
**********************************************************

lines I don not want
lines I don not want
lines I don not want
```

Desired output:

```
A sentence here:
********************************************************
lines I want
lines I want
lines I want
**********************************************************
```

I can get the script to work if I explicitly type out `A sentence here` and `\*` 58 times within the call to awk, but cleanliness and readability I would prefer to do something like below:

```
pat1="A sentence here"
pat2=`printf -- '\*%.s' {1..58} ; echo`
pat2=${pat2//\\/\\\\}
awk -v pat1="${pat1}" -v pat2="${pat2}" '/{pat1}/ {p=1}; p; /{pat2}/ {p=0}' $1
```

Where the first positional variable is the input file. The above code returns nothing. I initially tried it without the substitution on `pat2`, but got the warning:

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\*' treated as plain `*'
```

I will have to run this command thousands of times and would ideally like a solution that is both clean and efficient. I'm not tied to using `awk` at all.

Edit:

I just noticed that even when I manually type the patterns into awk, I still receive the warning message. I am likely not passing the variables to awk correctly.

Comment: This works: `awk '/:$/,/^\*{58}$/'`.  But I'm cheating. :)

Comment: @steeldriver I don't understand the `~` syntax in the answers you referenced, but I just tried `awk -v pat1="${pat1}" -v pat2="${pat2}" '$0 ~ pat1 {p=1}; p; $0 ~ pat2 {p=0}' $1` with no luck.

Comment: Sorry it appears I misunderstood your question - please ignore. Although FWIW it *does* appear to produce your desired output, for me.

Comment: See also [Pass shell variable as a /pattern/ to awk](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120806)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. The problem here is with `-v var=value` doing some backslash processing. While the other question is about doing a regexp match with an awk variable. It just so happens that one of the answers there addresses the specific issue in this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several options here:

- pat1, pat2 treated as regexps:

  ```
  pat1="A sentence here"
  pat2='\*{58}'
  export pat1 pat2
  awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["pat1"], $0 ~ ENVIRON["pat2"]'
  ```

  Note that `mawk` and versions of `gawk` prior to 4.0.0 do not support the `{}` extended regular expression operator. For old versions of `gawk`, you can pass the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable to make it recognise it.

  Here using the `start-condition, end-condition [{action}]` approach, but you could do the same with your `p` flag approach.
- pat1, pat2 treated as fixed strings:

  ```
  pat1="A sentence here"
  pat2=$(printf '*%.0s' {1..58})
  export pat1 pat2
  awk 'index($0, ENVIRON["pat1"]), index($0, ENVIRON["pat2"])'
  ```

  Here, `index()` searches for the *needle* (the variable content) anywhere in the *haystack* (the current record (line)), but you could also do a simple full-line comparison:

  ```
  awk '"" $0 == ENVIRON["pat1"], "" $0 == ENVIRON["pat2"]'
  ```

  (the `""` is to force a string comparison even in cases where both `$0` and `ENVIRON["patx"]` are numerical).

Avoid using `-v` to pass data that may contain backslash characters as `awk` does some C escape sequence (`\n`, `\b`, `\\`...) processing on them so you'd need to escape the backslashes (and with GNU `awk` 4.2 or above, [values that start with `@/` and end in `/` are also a problem](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants)). Same goes for variables passed like `awk '...code...' awkvar="$shellvar"`. Use `ENVIRON` or `ARGV` instead.

See [this answer to a related question](/a/120806) for further details.

Comment: The first approach did not give the desired output (unless I screwed something up), but the second approach worked great!

Comment: @dayne, is you `awk` `mawk` or an older version of `gawk`? Can you tell which implementation and version?

Comment: Looks like I am using GNU Awk 3.1.7 -- based on `awk -Wversion 2>/dev/null || awk --version`. It could certainly just be a version issue.

Comment: @dayne, yes, like I said, in old versions of `gawk`, you had to set gawk in POSIX mode or use `--re-interval`. Best is to run `awk` as `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk '....'` so it works whether `awk` is `gawk` or any other `awk`. That was changed in 4.0.0 released in 2011.