# How to grep variable pattern which is in first column

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I want to grep variable pattern which is in first column.

```
$ cat test.txt    
abc.xyz   
abc.def
pqr.tap
pqr.abc
abc.mnp
mnp.abc
abc.pqr
abc.mob
```

If variable pattern is `abc` then output should be

```
abc.xyz
abc.def
abc.mnp
abc.pqr
abc.mob
```

If variable pattern is `mnp` then output should be

```
mnp.abc
```

If pattern is not variable then I can do by command (For pattern mnp)

```
awk -F"." '{ if($1 == "mnp") print $0;}' test.txt
```

Comment: `grep '^abc'` or `awk '/^abc/'`

Answer (score 1):

Lets say:

```
pt="abc"
awk -v variable="$pt" -F"." '$1 ~ variable {print $0}' test.txt
```

More of this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk)

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you explain command in depth?

Comment: In the command `variable ` is an awk variable for which a shell variable `pt` was assigned. With filed separator `.` we get `$1` and compare it with `variable` and if it matches it prints the whole line.from the file `test.txt`. As for why to use awk variable, refer the aforementioned link.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the same line format you can simply grep "abc." (or whatever before the point including the point):

```
grep abc. file.txt
```