# How to use command-line argument as awk regex matching expression?

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I have the following awk script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS  = "";
}

value ~ "MYVALUE" # silly test
{
    print "1 - " substr($0, 235, 12);
}

$235 ~ "M" {
    print "2 - " substr($0, 235, 12);
}

{
    if(value == substr($0, 235, 12))
    {
        print "3 - " substr($0, 235, 12);
    }
    if(match(value,substr($0, 235, 12)))
    {
        print "4 - " substr($0, 235, 12);
    }
}

END {
    print "exit"
}
```

I run it as: `./script.awk -v value="MYVALUE" my_file`

This is my RHEL 5.5's awk:

```
$ ls -l  $(which awk)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 10  2015 /bin/awk -> gawk
$ gawk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.5
```

1 and 2 work. As an aside, if, in 2, i put the `{` in a newline, like:

```
$235 ~ "M" 
{
    print "2 - " substr($0, 235, 12);
}
```

then the output is the full matched line, not just the print.

What i would like to do is use `value` to match a regex, but it always fails. Something like:

```
$235...$247 ~ value
```

I saw examples([[1831722](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28049285/1831722)][[unix/27410](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120795/27410)]) of matching a single character, but not an expression.

**EDIT**

For clarity, i want to match lines that have no field separator, using a command-line parameter passed to awk and using it against a multi-character offset of the line. I hacked some python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

t   = 'ABC'
rg  = '^.{235,235}' + t
rgx = re.compile(rg)
tt  = '00000ABC00'
if(rgx.match(tt)):
    print "OK"
else:
    print "KO"
```

Only for this use-case awk would probably be faster since the files in question are quite big.

Comment: could you not reverse the operands? `"M" ~ value` ?

Comment: so youre doing value ~ "MYVALUE" , but then on command-line you show -v value="MYVALUE" . Please clarify this part. You are effectively checking same thing against itself, but my understanding is that you want to specify a field number like $1. Is there an example of actual input, output, and actual variable that you can provide ?

Comment: @Serg true, `value ~ "MYVALUE"` is wrong, i was just testing (a stupid test). One field is not enough  because this is a text file with long lines where the fields are defined by offsets, there is no separator character. So i want to compare either with substr on $0 or with a range like ($5,$6,...$,15) ~ parameterValue.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old but I thought I'd add a few comments if anyone else ends up here. Firstly, to create a range of fields, you can seperate them with `,`, so

```
$235, $247 ~ value { ... action here ... }
```

The output of the `substr` function can also be used directly to try and find a match if wanted:

```
substr($0, 235, 12) ~ value { ... action here ... }
```

Also, you seem to have found that placement of *some* of the braces are important. With each match, action pair, either the match, or the action can be an implicit default (match all, or print $0) so the change of

```
$235 ~ "M" {  print "2 - " substr($0, 235, 12);  }
```

to

```
$235 ~ "M" 
{  print "2 - " substr($0, 235, 12);  }
```

changes the meaning from `print this substring only when field 235 is an M`, to `whenever field 235 is an M print the whole record, AND for every record, print the substring`. so this could be used if, for example, you needed to perform several checks against the substring for each record, your first action could just be:

```
BEGIN { FS="" }
# oursubstr will be updated first for each record.
{ oursubstr = substr($0, 235, 12) } 
oursubstr ~ value { ... action ... }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.

```
{
    if(substr($0, 235, 12) ~ value)
    {
        print "4 - " substr($0, 235, 12)
        next
    }
    else
    {
        print "4 - NOK"
        next
    }
}
```

Comment: But it's a bit clumsy...