# AWK different result

Tags: awk, rhel, for

I was searching for List of Open Files based on Ips amd Processes. I used below command

```
    for i in `sudo netstat -tulpna|awk '{print $5}'|grep -E "[0-9]{3}"|grep -v "^192\|10"|cut -f1 -d ":"`;do sudo netstat -tulpna|awk '/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/ {print $7}';done
    26181/java
26181/java
26181/java
26181/java
26181/java
26181/java
26181/java
26181/java
26181/java
26181/java
26181/java
26181/java
```

Works ok if i add single quote and in awk condition /XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/ i give static value it will print 7th column

But if i use Double quotes and /$i/ variable

```
for i in `sudo netstat -tulpna|awk '{print $5}'|grep -E "[0-9]{3}"|grep -v "^192\|10"|cut -f1 -d ":"`;do sudo netstat -tulpna|awk "/$i/ {print $7}";done
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:62778          ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:35708         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:40920         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:40918         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:31211         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:35708         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:40920         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:40918         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:31211         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:35708         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:40920         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:40918         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:31211         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:35708         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:40920         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:40918         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443            XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:31211         ESTABLISHED 26181/java
```

When it should only be printing column 7. What i'm missing here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `awk` script:

```
awk "/$i/ {print $7}"
```

Here, `$7` is expanded by the shell and is most likely empty, resulting in the command

```
awk '/something/ {print }'
```

Instead, you may escape the `$` in `$7` from the shell:

```
awk "/$i/ {print \$7}"
```

This is ok in a short `awk` script like this. In a more complicated script, one should probably pass `$i` into `awk` using `-v variable="$i"` and use `variable` to `match()` against the lines (or use `~` as [αғsнιη shows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422735/116858)).

Comment: Sorry for late reply, It worked Perfectly. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

You should first pass `$i` as variable of `for ...;do ... ;done` to an `awk` variable then match it's value as a pattern like below:

```
... | awk -v list="$i" '$0 ~ list {print $7}'; done
```

<sup>see [Pass shell variable as a /pattern/ to awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120788/72456) for more.</sup>