# awk + set variable inside the awk

Tags: bash, awk

The following simple `bash` script prints the row number (from the file `list.txt`):

```bsh
function get_row

{ 
  
[[ $1 = 1 ]] &&  awk '{print $1}' list.txt
[[ $1 = 2 ]] &&  awk '{print $2}' list.txt
 
} 


get_row 1
get_row 2
```

But I would like to write it more elegantly.

Is it possible to set `$1` as variable as `awk '{print $val}'`,
so that if I call a function as `get_row 1`, the variable `$val` gets the value `1`?

Comment: This doesn't print rows. It will print the 1st or 2nd _column_ (field) of every line in the input file. Is that what you want? Or do you want the actual row (e.g. line 2) to be printed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
function get_column
{ 
    awk -v val=$1 '{print $val}' list.txt
}
```

Above is returning the column match with `$1` passing to the function. if you really need print the line match with line number in `$1` from function, instead use below.

```
function get_row
{ 
    awk -v val=$1 'NR==val{print ; exit}' list.txt
}
```

Or let shell evaluated and set the `val` value and print that within `awk` as following:

```
function get_column
{ 
    awk '{print $val}' val=$1 list.txt
}
```

```
function get_row
{ 
    awk 'NR==val{print ; exit}' val=$1 list.txt
}
```

Here you are passing `val` with only numbers and [if `val` was contain *backslash* escape character you will encounter a problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120806/72456) which `awk` does C escape sequence processing on values passed via `-v val=` and a shell variable with `val="\\n"` will change to value with `\n` by *awk*.

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
field=$1 awk '{print $ENVIRON["field"]}'
```

it works in all POSIX compliant system, and you don't have to worry about code injection when using `-v val=`

Also the function should be named `get_column` instead of `get_row`.