# How can I search matching pattern (stored in a variable) in a file using awk?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, vim, vi

I have a log file in which I need to check if there are any error messages, if there are, extract the error message to another file.

Like this I may have error file for the different file have different log patterns. So how can I search matching pattern using a variable?

As I want to create one generic `.sh` file for all log files. Suppose I have one file in which I want to search to pattern and print in another file `$pat1="ERROR MESSAGE"` `$pat2="RAISE_ERROR_SEEN"`. I want all lines from file b/w these two patterns.

Using variable only.

Comment: Possibly related: [Pass shell variable as a /pattern/ to awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk)

Comment: I tried to improve this but I still don't understand what you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 awk "/""$pat1""/,/""$pat2""/" test.log | grep -v "$pat3" > Error.bk
```

- will print the context between `$pat1` and `$pat2`
- Since we have space in the first variable, use double quotes twice.

Answer (score 0):

in a more simple way:

```
grep -e "$pat1\|$pat2" filename > resultfile
```

Comment: being careful with any regular-expression special characters in `$pat`

Comment: you are right but I only considered his concern in his question.

Comment: Hi,
Actually I want to work on awk only as I need to add more filters code and logic to process all log files.

Comment: OK!then please complete your question.