# how to awk user input

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I'm trying to match a pattern and then print out two lines after it. I'm successfully able to do it with the following code.

```
awk '/'202404'/{c=3}c&&c--' consolelog.log > testing.txt
```

I'm trying to replace the `202404` with something I can enter in the terminal. So far I have tried

```
echo "Enter peak value"
read peak
awk '/${peak}/{c=3}c&&c--' consolelog.log > testing.txt
```

But it does not work.

I don't necessarily need to use awk, grep or sed or anything will do. I just need to match a user inputted pattern and print 2 lines after it.

***UPDATE*****
I was playing around with it and I got it to work. It was something I totally missed. Here's what I did.

`awk 'c&&!--c;/'$peak'/{c=2}' consolelog.log > testing.txt`

Comment: What does your data look like? Are you interested in substring matches of the peak value (as `2404` in the string `202404`) or only exact matches? To match exactly, it would be helpful to see the data.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I want exact matches because, the max value i need is "202404" and in the raw data, the 2 lines after the value shows me the location i need. For example, the raw data looks similar to this

peak value =202404 <br>


***********************<br>


at location J512<br>

Comment: With all due respect, your answer is bad to the point of potentially being dangerous.   I encourage you to look at [DopeGhoti's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492070/80216#492076) below and  [glenn jackman's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120788/80216#120795) to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
echo "Enter peak value"
read peak
awk '/${peak}/{c=3}c&&c--' consolelog.log > testing.txt
```

This does not work because strong quotes prevent the shell from performing variable expansion.  This is good because `awk` uses a lot of syntax that weak quotes would make very difficult to use.

There are, however, ways to use environment variables within an `awk` script.

You can declare your own variable:

```
read peak
awk -vpeak="$peak" '$0 ~ peak { c=3 } c&&c--' consolelog.log > testing.txt
```

Or you can just tell `awk` to look at the one you just used `read` to fill:

```
read peak
export peak
awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["peak"] { c=3 } c&&c--' consolelog.log > testing.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "Enter peak value"
read peak
awk '/'"${peak}"'/{c=3}c&&c--' consolelog.log > testing.txt
```

Try this.

You need to close single quotes, and then you can use your Bash variable. I recommend placing it in a double-quote environment because otherwise it would cause trouble with other arguments to `awk`.

Comment: No, you should not inject code into scripts like that. `awk` can read environment variables and it can take values on the command line with `-v`.

Comment: Is security a big concern? If it is, you might be right, but IMHO it is not important for this script. Needs more input from OP.

Comment: Dancing around with `'`s and `"` and switching quoting modes inline like this _does_ work, but it's poor practice because it's already starting off as hard to read, and future-you six months from now at 4AM trying to parse this when your process just tipped over is going to want to go back in time six months and educate emself with a blunt object.

Comment: Security may not be a big concern for _this_ user, but remember that by presenting an answer, others may copy and paste your code into systems where security _is_ a concern.