# When using AWK with a variable pattern, can't get IF ELSE statement working

Tags: awk, scripting

The AWK statement uses the variable $ip to search each line, but I need to print the variable $ip NOT FOUND in the ELSE statement for ips that are not found in the config.

Can't get it to work with IF ELSE, to reuse the $ip variable in the ELSE statement, so it would print 999.999.999.999 NOT IN CONFIG!

also, if possible to not use redundant getline getline getline's, like maybe a  way to just skip 3 lines?

```
 declare -a iplist=(
 "192.168.0.10" 
 "192.168.0.20" 
 "192.168.0.30" 
 "999.999.999.999"
)

for ip in "${iplist[@]}"; do

awk "/$ip/" '{if {print $0; getline; getline; getline; print $0; print "-----"} else {print "/$ip/" "NOT FOUND"}' /home/user/D1/config

### BELOW WORKS - But, need the IF ELSE Statement ###
awk "/$ip/"'{print $0; getline; getline; getline; print $0; print "-----"}' /home/user/D1/config
done
```

config file contents:

```
ip=192.168.0.10
mask=255.255.255.0
allow=on
text=off
path=/home/user/D1/test/server1
-----
ip=192.168.0.20
mask=255.255.255.0
allow=on
text=off
path=/home/user/D1/test/server1
-----
ip=192.168.0.30
mask=255.255.255.0
allow=on
text=off
path=/home/user/D1/test/server1
-----
```

Desired output:

```
ip=192.168.0.10
path=/home/user/D1/test/server1
-----
ip=192.168.0.20
path=/home/user/D1/test/server1
-----
ip=192.168.0.30
path=/home/user/D1/test/server1
-----
ip=192.168.0.30
path=/home/user/D1/different-path-than-line-above/server1
-----
ip=999.999.999.999 NOT IN CONFIG
-----
```

Comment: FYI that's not a recommended way to [Pass shell variable as a /pattern/ to awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk)

Comment: sorry I was trying to show what I was starting with,  I changed it now to where I'm stuck

Comment: Looks like you are missing a closing `}` in the broken example.

Comment: Your posted expected output with just the 1 IP address repeated in every block doesn't make sense wrt your posted sample input. Please fix it.

Comment: I fixed that.   however, there can be entries with the same IP, but a different "path", as I have also changed.    sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The right approach is to just call awk once with the list of IPs, create an array of tags/names to values (`f[]` below) and just access the values by their names. No shell loop (which would be extremely slow), and no getlines (see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for why those are usually best avoided) required:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

declare -a iplist=(
    '192.168.0.10'
    '192.168.0.20'
    '192.168.0.30'
    '999.999.999.999'
)

awk -v iplist="${iplist[*]}" '
    BEGIN {
        split(iplist,tmp)
        for (idx in tmp) {
            ip = tmp[idx]
            cnt[ip] = 0
        }
        OFS = "="
        sep = "-----"
    }
    {
        tag = val = $0
        sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/^[^=]+=/,"",val)
        f[tag] = val
    }
    $0 == sep {
        ip = f["ip"]
        if ( ip in cnt ) {
            cnt[ip]++
            print "ip", ip
            print "path", f["path"]
            print sep
        }
        delete f
    }
    END {
        for (ip in cnt) {
            if ( cnt[ip] == 0 ) {
                print "ip", ip " NOT IN CONFIG"
                print sep
            }
        }
    }
' config
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh
ip=192.168.0.10
path=/home/user/D1/test/server1
-----
ip=192.168.0.20
path=/home/user/D1/test/server1
-----
ip=192.168.0.30
path=/home/user/D1/test/server1
-----
ip=999.999.999.999 NOT IN CONFIG
-----
```

I use `tag = val = $0`, etc. to separate the tags from their values rather than relying on setting `FS="="` since `=` can appear in UNIX directory or file names and so could appear in a `path`.

Comment: it works, but sometimes there are duplicate IP addresses in the configuration file, and it needs to find those as well, as the duplicates have native paths.  well that be a big change?

Comment: It's no change at all - best I can tell the script will behave as desired as-is. Did you try it? If there's a case it doesn't work for then include that case in the sample input/output in your question.

Comment: yes, I did try it.  also the   sep -----    dashes are added to the config by the system daemon, so it would be best to not print them, but  let the statement print whats there.  like maybe a print the next line syntax.

Comment: wrt `it would be best to not print them` - if you don't want them printed then don't include them in your expected output. It sounds like you have a few important  things not covered in your question so  update your question to contain all relevant information and an accurate example.

Comment: those are pretty much all the important details to add. originally I just wanted to use a one liner with the IF ELSE to keep it simple for other users.  Is that possible? or  is the IF ELSE statement not capable of having the ELSE use the $ip variable match

Comment: Yes, you can use an else, I'm personally not going to help you write code that requires a shell loop and multiple passes of the input file to work but maybe someone else will. Good luck!