# How do we use sed to replace specific line with a string variable?

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed

Lets say for example I have a `file.txt` containing 3 lines:

```
hello
hello
hello
```

I have a variable called `line=1` and a variable string `substitute=hello1`. I want to replace the string in the line described by the variable `line` with my new string variable called `substitute`.

The resultant change to `files.txt` would look like:

```
hello1
hello
hello
```

How would I use `sed` to do this? Or `awk`? If thats what you are in to, as long as I can input variables that I can change in a while loop.

Comment: You seem to be performing text substitution in a shell script. While many possibilities immediately come to mind to help you, contributors will be able to help you better if you post at least an excerpt of the script. Also, can you edit your post to add more information about the text to be found and replaced? Is it "simply" the entire line you want to replace or are there other boundary conditions?

Comment: Also, you aren't the first person ever trying to do that. The same question has been already asked and answered here or at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the value of `$substitute` doesn't contain special characters, you can simply do:

```bsh
line=1
substitute=hello1
sed -i "${line}s/.*/$substitute/"  file.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

With `perl`:

```bash
export line substitute
perl -pi -e '$_ = $ENV{substitute} . "\n" if $. == $ENV{line}' file.txt
```

same with GNU `awk`:

```bash
export line substitute
gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk '
  NR == ENVIRON["line"] {$0 = ENVIRON["substitute"]}
  {print}' file.txt
```

Using `sed` is not ideal here, even with those that support a perl-like `-i` option, as we'd need to do some post-processing on the value of `$substitute` if it may contain backslash, `&`, the `s` command delimiter or newline characters. See [How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059) for details on that.

In `gawk`, **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`

Comment: Consider `line="$line" substitute="$substitute" gawk '...'` on a single line so you don't have to export the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Without further information, the following `awk` program should work:

```
awk -v where="$line" -v what="$substitute" 'FNR==where {print what; next} 1' file.txt
```

- It will import the shell variables `$line` and `$substitute` into `awk` variables `where` and `what`.
- When processing the file, it will by default simply print the current line ( the seemingly stray `1` outside the rule block `{ ... }`).
- When the per-file line counter `FNR` is equal to the line number stored in `where`, we print the substitute string `what` instead, and skip execution to the next input line.

Note that `awk` doesn't edit files in-place, so you have to redirect the output and rename the result file once you are satisfied. Alternatively, with sufficiently new versions of GNU `awk`, you can use the `-i inplace` option to modify the file in-place.

**Note** that (as pointed out by αғsнιη/Stéphane Chazelas/Ed Morton) the above will show erratic behavior if your `substitute` string contains the literal `\`, since this method expands escape sequences. In that case, the `awk`-based alternative solution in Stéphane Chazelas' answer with exporting the variable and referencing it as `ENVIRON["substitute"]` would do the trick (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120806) for more information).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `line >0` and always is *int*, you could do:

```
<infile head -n$(($line-1)); printf '%s\n' "$substitute"; tail -n +$(($line+1)) infile
```

Note that this will append the `$substitute` value to the end of file if line_number `$line` > file's_number_of_lines

Answer (score 1):

```
$   line=1 substitute=hello1
$ sed -nf - <<eof file 
  $line r $(t=$(mktemp);printf '%s\n' "$substitute" > "$t";echo "$t")
  $line!p
eof
```

We use a heredoc to pass the sed code. The sed code is reading a file and placing jts contents on the stdout and suppressing the original line by virtue of the `-n` option.

Answer (score 0):

**If:**

- `$line` contains an actual line number of the file (is non-zero, is not greater than the last line), and
- `$substitute` is not equal to a single period (`.`)

then you could use an `ed` script:

```
printf '%dc\n%s\n.\nw\nq' "$line" "$substitute" | ed -s input
```

This sends several lines of commands as input to `ed`:

1. `c`hange the line represented by `$line`
2. to the `$substitute` value
3. end the change with `.`
4. `w`rite the changed file back to disk
5. `q`uit ed

Of course, since there's no error-checking, `$line` and `$substitute` need to abide by the assumptions at the top. A surrounding shell script could sanity-check the `$line` variable, but entering a bare `.` as input to `ed` would require additional effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ""$line"s/.*/"$substitute"/g" filename
```

Comment: Please take note of the link in [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/617627/117549) regarding the need to escape arbitrary data in (e.g.) the $substitute variable.