# Passing argument to AWK

Tags: awk

I have the following AWK command which works well.

```
awk -v RS="\n+?[$]{4}\n+?" '/HMDB0000008/' test.xt
```

However what I want is to be able to call it from the command line and pass an argument so that it can find what I want.

For example, something like this:

```
awk -f var=HMDB0000008 RS="\n+?[$]{4}\n+?" '/$var/' test.txt
```

However this does not seem to work. Can you tell me what would be the best way?

Thank you

Comment: See [Pass shell variable as a /pattern/ to awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass shell variable as a /pattern/ to awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk)

Comment: Why [get an answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65009434/1745001) and then immediately ask a question about that answer here on SE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

awk doesn't use `$` to expand variables, additionally they are passed with the -v option not -f.  Also strings within `/.../` will be treated as a regex pattern so you need to use the `~` pattern match operator against the entire line (`$0`):

```
awk -v var=HMDB0000008 -v RS="\n+?[$]{4}\n+?" '$0 ~ var' test.txt
```

Comment: Also awk regexps don't have perl's `+?` operator. Even if it was supported, it wouldn't make much sense here, the first one would make no difference compared the `+` and the second is superflous as a non-greedy `\n+?` followed by nothing is the same as just `\n`. (using a regexp as RS is also not standard/portable)

Comment: See also `index()` to find substrings.