# Passing variable to AWK not working inside a loop

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, perl, yaml

I have this awk statement that reads a YAML file and outputs a particular value. I need to loop this awk inside a loop where I read a key value from a list of values and pass that key to awk.

The YAML file has this structure:

```
abc:
  NAME: Bob
  OCCUPATION: Technician
def:
  NAME: Jane
  OCCUPATION: Engineer
```

Say I want to get key `abc` `OCCUPATION` value of `TECHNICIAN`, through googling I managed to construct an awk statement that gives what I want

```
> awk 'BEGIN{OFS=""} /^[^ ]/{ f=/^abc:/; next } f{ if (sub(/:$/,"")) abc=$2; else print abc,$1 $2}' test.yml| grep "OCCUPATION:" | cut -d':' -f2
Technician
```

However passing -v option to awk does not seem to give anything if I use this loop:

```
items="abc,def"
for item in $(echo $items | sed "s/,/ /g"); 
do
 echo $item;
 awk -v name="$item" 'BEGIN{OFS=""} /^[^ ]/{ f=/^\name:/; next } f{ if (sub(/:$/,"")) name=$2; else print name,$1 $2}' test.yml| grep "OCCUPATION:" | cut -d':' -f2; 
done
```

I get just the debug echos I set out

```
abc
def
```

Where am I going wrong? I thought the variable should be interpreted correctly inside awk?

EDIT: Based on steeldrivers comment I have changed the input a little

```
items="abc,def"
for item in $(echo $items | sed "s/,/ /g"); 
do
 echo $item;
 awk -v name="$item" 'BEGIN{OFS=""} /^[^ ]/{ f=name; next } f{ if (sub(/:$/,"")) name=$2; else print name,$1 $2}' test.yml| grep "OCCUPATION:" | cut -d':' -f2; 
done
```

However now I am getting all values for `OCCUPATION` printed:

```
abc
Technician
Engineer
def
Technician
Engineer
```

I tried to use the `~` operator but I think I am not using it right as it is giving me errors, so I decided to just parse the value directly, but this is giving duplicates :/

Comment: You can't use a variable inside a regexp constant `/.../`, you need to use the explicit `~` operator - see [Pass shell variable as a /pattern/ to awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk)

Comment: I tried something similar without the ~ operator, just the value passed and it seems to work but gives duplicate results :/

Comment: The variable equivalent to `f=/^abc:/` would be something like `f = ($0 ~ "^" name ":")` however I can't help feeling you would be better served by a proper YAML-aware tool

Comment: that works but I can see how this is not a very clean approach! unfortunately I am constrained by base bash, cant install jq or use python or something else to process this :(

Comment: Do you have perl installed?     The YAML module has been included as one of the standard core perl modules since around perl v5.14 in 2013.   Try running `perl --version`, if it's >= 5.14, you have the YAML module.  Also try `perl -MYAML -e ''` - if that compiles without error, you definitely have the YAML module installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When working with structured text like YAML or JSON or XML, you really should use a parser that "understands" the structure.   There are several specific command-line tools for various kinds of structured text (e.g. `xmlstarlet` for xml, `jq` for json, and **[yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/)** for yaml), and most programming/scripting languages have libraries for parsing and processing structured text.

Here's how to do it in perl, using the perl core YAML module:

(this requires a version of perl >= 5.14, which is when the YAML module was included as a standard part of the core module distribution.  perl 5.14 was released in 2013.  For earlier versions of perl, you can install YAML with `cpan`).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use YAML qw(LoadFile);

my $file = shift;            # first arg is the input filename
my $data = LoadFile($file);  # load the yaml data into a hashref variable

# loop over the remaining args (i.e. the keys)
foreach my $item (@ARGV) {
    print "$item\n";
    print $$data{$item}{'OCCUPATION'}, "\n";
}
```

Save this as, e.g. `yaml.pl` and make it executable with `chmod +x yaml.pl`.

If your yaml data is save in a file called `input.yaml`, you can run it like this:

```
$ ./yaml.pl input.yaml abc def
abc
Technician
def
Engineer
```

Like awk or sed, this can also be condensed into an inscrutable one-liner:

```
$ perl -MYAML=LoadFile -E '$data=LoadFile(shift);foreach (@ARGV) {say $_;say $$data{$_}{"OCCUPATION"}}' input.yaml abc def
abc
Technician
def
Engineer
```

perl can also automatically split the arguments for you.  e.g. if you change the `foreach` loop to:

```
foreach my $item (split /\s*,\s*/,join(",",@ARGV)) {
```

you can run it as:

```
$ ./yaml.pl input.yaml abc def
```

or

```
$ ./yaml.pl input.yaml "abc,def"
```

or any combination (asuuming hypothetical ghi and jkl keys):

```
$ ./yaml.pl input.yaml "abc,def" ghi jkl
```

Comment: Note: once you've written a little perl (or whatever) script to extract the data you want, you can always use it within a shell script, same as you can call awk or yq or sed or whatever.  Part of the idea of unix, and the point of learning languages like awk or sed or perl, is to use them to build your own custom tools when you need them.  Some of them will be general purpose tools that you use often, some will be one-off disposable tools that you never use again.   Learning to think like a tool-maker is a valuable habit that will pay off for the rest of your life.

Answer (score 6):

Using `yq` (the `jq` wrapper from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) to parse the YAML on the command line (or in a script):

```
$ yq -r '.abc.OCCUPATION' file.yml
Technician
```

Giving it `abc` and `def` in a shell loop:

```bsh
$ for thing in abc def; do yq -r --arg node "$thing" '$node,.[$node].OCCUPATION' file.yml; done
abc
Technician
def
Engineer
```

or, for tab-delimited columns:

```
$ for thing in abc def; do yq -r --arg node "$thing" '[$node,.[$node].OCCUPATION] | @tsv' file.yml; done
abc     Technician
def     Engineer
```

That is, call `yq` with `--arg` followed by the `yq` variable's name that you want to set, and then the value that you're setting it to.  Then use the variable in the `yq` expression.  This works *identically* in `jq`.

Without a shell loop and instead taking the values from the top-level keys:

```
$ yq -r 'foreach keys[] as $node (.;.;[$node,.[$node].OCCUPATION]|@tsv)' file.yml
abc     Technician
def     Engineer
```

---

There is a few other tools called `yq` out there that all do YAML parsing.  If you install `yq` using `snap` on Ubuntu, you get a version from someone called Mike Farah.  It works differently and I tend to use it for converting to JSON and then pipe the data to `jq`:

```
$ yq -j e file.yml | jq -r '.abc.OCCUPATION'
Technician
```

```
$ for thing in abc def; do yq -j e file.yml | jq -r --arg node "$thing" '$node,.[$node].OCCUPATION'; done
abc
Technician
def
Engineer
```

or, for tab-delimited columns:

```
$ for thing in abc def; do yq -j e file.yml | jq -r --arg node "$thing" '[$node,.[$node].OCCUPATION] | @tsv'; done
abc     Technician
def     Engineer
```

Answer (score 3):

you don't need shell loop to processing a simple text when you have proper text-processing tools such as [awk](/questions/tagged/awk); following we used GNU *awk* for that we can define multu-char RS and RT which is back-reference to the current matched RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)[a-z]+:\n' 'rt ~ /^abc:\n$/ { print $NF; exit } { rt=RT }' infile
Technician
```

to strictly checking that the reported value has really the *"OCCUPATION"* key and also pass key/header from the variable instead of hardcoding them, you could do:

```
$ awk -v hdr='abc' -v key='OCCUPATION' -v RS='(^|\n)[a-z]+:\n' -F'\n' \
'rt ~ ("^" hdr ":\n") { 
     for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
         if(match($i, "^\\s*" key ":\\s*" )) { print substr($i, RSTART+RLENGTH); exit }
}
{ rt=RT }' infile
Technician
```

Answer (score 3):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -v key='abc' -v fld='OCCUPATION' '
    /^[^[:space:]]/{ inKeyBlock = (index($1,key":")==1) }
    inKeyBlock && (index($1,fld":")==1) { sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,""); print }
' file
Technician
```

In the unlikely event that you don't have a POSIX awk or some other awk that supports character classes then just change `[[:space:]]` to `[ \t]`, and `[^[:space:]]` to `[^ \t]`.

Comment: Do you prefer `[[:space:]]` to `[[:blank:]]`?  I mean, a space and a tab is what `[[:blank:]]` matches... At least in the POSIX locale.

Comment: Yes, I always use `[[:space:]]` unless I **need** to exclude newline and a few other whitespace chars and then I use `[[:blank:]]`, that way I don't get a surprise when I'm writing code that can contain multi-line records (or evolves to such). I also find the name `[[:blank:]]` to be a little misleading since it sounds like it's only matching a blank char whereas IMHO `[[:space:]]` is a bit clearer as matching all spaces but that's a very minor thing.

Answer (score 1):

Also using `awk`:

```bsh
awk -F'[[:space:]]+' '$1 == "" {if (s == "abc:" && $2 == "OCCUPATION:") print $3; next} {s=$1}' file
Technician
```

This would fail if the occupation was e.g. "Network technician", or anything containing a space though. So to guard against that:

```bsh
awk -F'[[:space:]]+' '$1 == "" {if (s == "abc:" && $2 == "OCCUPATION:") { sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,""); print }; next} {s=$1}' file
Technician
```

Ed Morton's solution `{ sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,""); print }` instead of `print $3` is valid also here.

Answer (score 0):

```
# var definitions to be used by sed
key='abc'
subkey='OCCUPATION'
s='[[:blank:]]'

# make vars plug worthy in LHS of sed
for i in \\ \[ ^ \$ . \* /;do
  key=${key//"$i"/\\"$i"}
  subkey=${subkey//"$i"/\\"$i"}
done

# invoke sed with the variables
sed -ne "
  /^$key:\$/,/^[^:]*:\$/ s/^$s$s*$subkey:$s*//p
" input.yaml
Technician
```