# Regex match shell variable as a pattern (case insensitively)

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, csv, gnu

A snippet of a typical tsv file I have used

```
10  Interstellar    Main Theme Extended UDVtMYqUAyw
11  Journey XvG78AmBLc4
12  Jurassic Park Music & Ambience  Amazing Soundscapes and Music   PPl__iyIg6w
13  Lord of the Rings   Sound of The Shire  chLZQtCold8
14  Lord of the Rings   The Shire: Sunset at Bag End    uBmbI8dzc-M
```

The following searches for lord (case insensitively) in 2nd column of all tsv files:

```bsh
awk '$2~IGNORECASE = 1;/lord/{print}' *.tsv 

13      Lord of the Rings       Sound of The Shire      chLZQtCold8
14      Lord of the Rings       The Shire: Sunset at Bag End    uBmbI8dzc-M
```

Now, I wanted to pass `Lord` as a bash environment variable:

```bsh
$ awk -v Pattern="Lord" '$2~Pattern{print}' *.tsv 
13      Lord of the Rings       Sound of The Shire      chLZQtCold8
14      Lord of the Rings       The Shire: Sunset at Bag End    uBmbI8dzc-M
```

### Problem

How to do the match of pattern case insensitively?

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```bsh
awk -v Pattern="lord" '$2~IGNORECASE = 1;Pattern{print}' *.tsv

awk -v Pattern="lord" 'IGNORECASE = 1;$2~Pattern{print}' *.tsv

awk -v Pattern="lord" 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1}  {$2~Pattern{print}}' *.tsv 

awk -v Pattern="Lord" '{IGNORECASE = 1; $2~Pattern}' *.tsv
```

## Refer

- [ignorecase in AWK - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228892/ignorecase-in-awk)
- [Pass shell variable as a /pattern/ to awk - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk)
- [Make Awk Command Case Insensitive](https://www.folkstalk.com/2012/01/make-awk-command-case-insensitive.html)

Comment: `awk -v Pattern="Lord" '{IGNORECASE = 1; $2~Pattern}'` does not work. awk -W version
GNU Awk 5.0.1

Comment: ... sorry I initially misread that as `awk -v Pattern="Lord" '{IGNORECASE = 1;} $2~Pattern' *.tsv` which also works but unnecessarily re-assigns `IGNORECASE = 1` for every record

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I doubt that `$2~IGNORECASE = 1;/lord/{print}` works the way you think it does - AFAIK it assigns value `1` to the variable `IGNORECASE`; compares the value of `$2` to the result (i.e. `$2 ~ 1`) and by default prints `$0` if the result is true; then compares `$0` case-insensitively against `/lord/` and *also* prints `$0` if that is true.

If your intent is to compare `$2` case-insensitively, you can use

```
gawk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1} $2 ~ /lord/{print}` *.tsv
```

or just

```
gawk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1} $2 ~ /lord/` *.tsv
```

The equivalent with a variable would be

```
gawk -v Pattern="lord" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1} $2 ~ Pattern' *.tsv
```

Note that `IGNORECASE` is not a standard awk feature - as far as I know, only GNU awk (`gawk`) supports it - for portability you can use `toupper` or `tolower` to get the input into a specific case.

Comment: Note though that the portable version will also be *wrong* in some (more unusual) cases, because comparing upper- or lower-cased text is not the same as comparing case-insensitively in Unicode, and under some locales. (It doesn't sound like gawk does exactly the right thing either, but it's *more often* right.)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `The following searches for lord (case insensitively) in 2nd column of all tsv files: awk '$2~IGNORECASE = 1;/lord/{print}' *.tsv` - no, it doesn't do that at all. It does a regexp comparison for $2 against the result of assigning IGNORECASE to 1 which is always true and so it prints the current line. It then looks for any string matching the regexp `lord` anywhere on the line and it found prints the line a second time. You probably meant to do `awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1} $2~/lord/' *.tsv` as that would do what you describe.

Don't use the word "pattern" in this context as it's highly ambiguous. You're using Pattern as a partial regexp match but describing it as if you want a full-word string match. So, please replace "pattern" with all 3 of string-or-regexp and partial-or-full and word-or-line everywhere it occurs in your question so we can help you come up with the right solution. See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more information.

Here are some possible solutions for what you may be trying to do:

Partial string match:

```
$ awk -v var="$var" -F'\t' 'index(tolower($2),tolower(var))' file.tsv
13  Lord of the Rings   Sound of The Shire  chLZQtCold8
14  Lord of the Rings   The Shire: Sunset at Bag End    uBmbI8dzc-M
```

Full-word string match:

```
$ awk -v var="$var" -F'\t' 'index(" "tolower($2)" ",tolower(var))' file.tsv
13  Lord of the Rings   Sound of The Shire  chLZQtCold8
14  Lord of the Rings   The Shire: Sunset at Bag End    uBmbI8dzc-M
```

Full-line string match:

```
$ awk -v var="$var" -F'\t' 'tolower($2) == tolower(var)' file.tsv
$
```

Partial regexp match:

```
$ awk -v var="$var" -F'\t' 'tolower($2) ~ tolower(var)' file.tsv
13  Lord of the Rings   Sound of The Shire  chLZQtCold8
14  Lord of the Rings   The Shire: Sunset at Bag End    uBmbI8dzc-M
```

Full-word regexp match:

```
$ awk -v var="$var" -F'\t' '(" "tolower($2)" ") ~ tolower(var)' file.tsv
13  Lord of the Rings   Sound of The Shire  chLZQtCold8
14  Lord of the Rings   The Shire: Sunset at Bag End    uBmbI8dzc-M
```

Full-line regexp match:

```
$ awk -v var="$var" -F'\t' 'tolower($2) ~ ("^"tolower(var)"$")' file.tsv
$
```

The above assumes your shell variable does not contain escape sequences or if it does you want them expanded. If that's not the case then use `ENVIRON[]` or `ARGV[]` to pass the value of the shell variable to awk instead of `-v`, see [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for details.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

Searching a pattern in second field of file:

```
perl -F"\t" -lane '$F[1] =~ /(?i)lord/ and print' input.tsv
```

- `-F"\t"` is because file is tsv
- `$F[1]` is second file of record because fields are zero-indexed.
- `(?i)` is case insensitive option in regex
- or modifier `i` may be used for case insensitivity as in

```
perl -F"\t" -lane '$F[1] =~ /lord/i and print' input.tsv
```

regex matching a shell variable may be done by `export` as in

```
export p=lord
perl -F"\t" -lane '$F[1] =~ /(?i)$ENV{p}/ and print' input.tsv
perl -F"\t" -lane '$F[1] =~ /$ENV{p}/i and print' input.tsv
```

Searching in all `.tsv` files of a folder:

```
perl -F"\t" -lane '$F[1] =~ /$ENV{p}/i and print' *.tsv
```

If you want filename with records, then following would do:

```
perl -F"\t" -lane '$F[1] =~ /$ENV{p}/i and print $ARGV. ":" .$_' *.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use **awk** and can use a tool dedicated to processing tabular data, like **GoCSV**, this is a snap.

Starting with the sample of data you provided, I made up some names and took a guess at "Journey":

**input.tsv**

| ID | Album | Track | Hash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Interstellar | Main Theme Extended | UDVtMYqUAyw |
| 11 | Journey |  | XvG78AmBLc4 |
| 12 | Jurassic Park Music & Ambience | Amazing Soundscapes and Music | PPl__iyIg6w |
| 13 | Lord of the Rings | Sound of The Shire | chLZQtCold8 |
| 14 | Lord of the Rings | The Shire: Sunset at Bag End | uBmbI8dzc-M |

1. set the shell variable `pattern`
2. **delim** to convert the TSV to CSV
3. **filter** on column 2 with the **-i** *case-invariant* **--regex** of that shell variable
4. **behead** to get just the matching rows
5. convert back to TSV:

```bsh
pattern='lord'
gocsv delim -i "\t" input.tsv              \
| gocsv filter -c 2 -i --regex "$pattern"  \
| gocsv behead                             \
| gocsv tsv

13      Lord of the Rings       Sound of The Shire      chLZQtCold8
14      Lord of the Rings       The Shire: Sunset at Bag End    uBmbI8dzc-M
```