# Tail Grep - Print surrounding lines until pattern is matched

Tags: awk, sed, grep, logs, tail

So here is my requirement.

I am tailing a log file and grepping on it.
I want to get some context on every grep result..
But the context should be "till a pattern is matched" and not the number of lines (which is what `grep -A/-B/-C` offer).

For example
Say here is my log..

`[l]` is prefixed to every log line. Also there will be prefix of `[logTypeA]` or `[logTypeB]`

```
[l][logTypeA] - Log line 1
[l][logTypeB] - Log line 2 
[l][logTypeA] - Log line 3 
.... 

Random data about Log line 3
....

[l][logTypeB] - Log line 4
```

Now my if my `tail` command was `tail -f log_file.log | grep "[logTypeA]"`, 
I'd get an output of

```
[l][logTypeA] - Log line 1
[l][logTypeA] - Log line 3
```

But I need contextual information for my grep result, and that context is NOT some number of lines, but rather till a particular pattern is matched (in this case [l])..

In the example I want my grep result to be

```
[l][logTypeA] - Log line 1
[l][logTypeA] - Log line 3 
.... 

Random data about Log line 3
....
```

From here ([How to show lines after each grep match until other specific match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21076/how-to-show-lines-after-each-grep-match-until-other-specific-match)), I tried `sed` command on my `tail` like

```
tail -f log_file.log | sed '/\[logTypeA\]/,/\[l\]/p'
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: `tail -f` gives buffered output and can not play with "past" and "future" range

Comment: In broad terms, write a simple script (I suggest in Awk) which groups related lines into "records" and then prints those records which match a particular pattern. Your question is too generic for it to make sense to show you a working script, but this is an extremely common task with Awk. Spend 30 minutes on a basic tutorial if you are unfamiliar with it, and you should be all set to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest 
what about tail -f with grep -A, which gives me 10 lines after..
How is my requirement different from this?

Comment: @tripleee Writing an awk script was my last resort.. 
Was just wondering if there was some existing command.

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. Your `sed` script looks like you want to print lines with `[l]` and all lines between them ... but without any further conditions, that's simply equivalent to all lines, to my understanding. I *guess* you want all `[l]` lines *which match a particular additional pattern* and all non-`[l]` lines after a match, but without further details, there are too many variables and guesses to write a useful script. It could probably done in `sed` instead if that's your preference, though Awk seems particularly suitable here.

Comment: @tripleee Sorry I was not clear in the question.. Have updated my question with more details..

Comment: Your `grep "[logTypeA]"` needs to escape the `[` or use `grep -F`. Currently it will print any line which contains `l` or `o` or `g` or `T` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely common pattern with Awk.  Collect related lines into "records", print the record when you have collected all of it if it matches a particular condition.

```
tail -f file |
awk '/\[l]/ { if (p && stored) print stored; stored = ""; p=0 }
    /\[logTypeA]/ { p=1 }
    { stored = stored (stored ? ORS : "") $0 }
    END { if (p) print stored }'
```

The `END` condition doesn't really make sense with a never-ending stream from `tail -f` but I include it for good measure, and to avoid pesky test failures when the last record you want to test with should be printed, but won't be without the `END` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably end up doing this with a perl one-liner.
You can do it in sed but it feels like it's beginning to hit up against the "unintentional turing-completeness" part of sed.

Perl one-liner (the `perl -ne` is really the take away here)

```
echo  '[l] boring\nboring data\n[l] boring\n[l]interesting\ndata\ndata\n[l]boring' |  perl -ne '
    if (/\[l\].*interesting/ ) { print $_; $collect=1 ; }
    elsif (/\[l\]/) {$collect=0 }
    elsif ($collect) {print $_}'
```

For reference, here is the sed one-liner that does the same thing. (Features of sed used: **b** to achieve a switch, **T** to achieve conditional execution).

```
echo  '[l] boring\nboring data\n[l] boring\n[l\]interesting\ndata\ndata\n[l]boring' |  sed -nE '/\[l\].*interesting/ {
p;
s/.*/collect/ ; x ; # store collect marker in the pattern space
b; # terminate processing
}

/\[l\]/ {
s/.*// ; x; # clear hold flag
b
}

/./ {
x;
s/collect/collect/;
T; x; p # print if we are collecting
}
'
```

Comment: The thing in the square brackets is a lowercase L, not the number 1.

Comment: The Perl script assumes that the interesting string occurs on the same line as the `[l]`. I don't know if that covers the OP's use case; my Awk script copes with matches in the subsequent related lines, too. (It's not very hard to make the Perl script also support this, though.)

Comment: @triplee good point.  It makes one-liner a lot simpler though :).

Comment: I've fixed the 1 to be a lowercase L (though haven't confirmed that the code runs)